# Sourcing Transformer with Specific Turns Ratio

Tags: transformer, components, high-voltage, component-selection, sourcing

I am looking at a building an electronics project that calls for a transformer with a specific turns ratio '1:4:50', and am trying to source a component. I am working on the project from this tutorial: https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/diy-stun-gun-circuit

When I search power transformers on Mouser or Digi-Key there is no option in the parametric search for turns ratio. The only category that does have a turns ratio option is 'Current Sense Transformers', but after reading up on these devices (used for metering AC current draw) they seem incorrect for my application. The purpose of this project is to use the transformer in "flyback mode", building up a large DC charge from a small AC signal at the input. I am assuming for this application I need a power transformer.

This part has been weirdly impossible to source, which seems strange as the application isn't that esoteric. Can anyone give advice on how I would go about searching for correct component?

Comment: You need to build it yourself so contact the designer and ask them what ferrite core is used and what diameter wires and what insulation ratings on the secondary. If you don't get this near-enough right it won't work. Happy hunting. Also why are you so fixated on killing bugs (previous questions etc..)?

Comment: I ***think*** transformers are often custom-made (*because* everyone wants different turns ratios). Luckily, it's not *too* difficult to make one by hand.

Comment: that device may be illegal in your country

Comment: @Ocanath Not enough experience, huh? https://www.hammerheadaudio.com/designs

Comment: @Ocanath High voltage is a new thing I'm messing around with as a hobby project, but I have a lot of experience electrical engineering. I linked this tutorial because its one of the few places I've found the transformer specs actually documented.

Comment: @Andyaka Thought this would be a fun concept to build a sound toy around, like a bug zapper with synthesizer controls. I've got some successful prototypes in my workshop from taking stuff apart, but actually sourcing components has been really challenging because it seems like no one gives clear documentation of specs.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima Sorry! You definitely know what you're doing. I thought it might be safer to be discouraging in this situation considering the destructive potential of such a circuit. Normally I wouldn't go there.

Comment: There's more going on in a transformer than just winding ratios.  You need to know the type of core (material, physical shape & size), wire diameters, insulation strength, etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformers are difficult to source in general. My recommendation based on past experience designing low volume one-off flyback transformers is to build your design around the transformer, not vice-versa. Coilcraft is an example of a company that sources stock transformers suitable for flyback applications.

I'm providing this as general advice for people designing transformer-based circuits. **DO NOT** use this design, or one like it, on a human being. High voltage converters are not toys and should be taken seriously.